# Typeorm UseIndex ignored when using take/limit for pagination

Tags: mariadb, nestjs, typeorm

I'm facing the following problem with TypeOrm's queryBuilder in a NestJs project (database is MariaDB).
I have a big query which looks like this:

```
const query = this.repository.createQueryBuilder('smp')
    .useIndex('IDX_my_index')
    .leftJoinAndMapMany('smp.results', Results, 'res', 'res.smp_id = smp.id');
    // ... lots of of maps but this is the main join
```

Because my tables handle millions of rows, i have to optimize the query, and the best solution we found so far is to force index uses, depending on where clauses.
When i retrieved results with offset/limit methods for pagination, the USE INDEX exists in the generated query, and i have a real performance boost:

```
const results = await query.limit(30).offset(30).getMany();

// DBeaver catches the request as something like
// SELECT ech.* FROM samples smp USE INDEX(IDX_my_index) LEFT JOIN ....
```

But because of the leftJoinAndMapMany, i have to use take/skip methods in order to have a consistent pagination. And when i use these methods, the USE INDEX doesn't appear in the generated query and i face a significant performance drop:

```
const results = await query.take(30).skip(30).getMany();

// DBeaver catches the request as something like
// SELECT DISTINCT distinctAlias.smp_id FROM (SELECT ech.* FROM samples smp LEFT JOIN .... ) ...
```

I'm not sure why, but TypeOrm just ignores the useIndex when using take/skip methods.

Do you have any clue/hack on how i could achieve this ?
I tried to upgrade typeorm to the latest version (0.3.17) but it doesn't solve the issue.

- Upgrading to the latest typeorm version.
- Hacks like: writing the USE INDEX in the createQueryBuilder(), addSelect()  or from() methods.